# Delete Button Calculator *Help*

Tags: ios, button, calculator, backspace

I have this code for my calculator that lets me delete one number at a time!

```
- (IBAction)deleteButton:(id)sender {
    NSString *string = [Screen text];
    int length = [string length];
    NSString *temp = [string substringToIndex:length-1];

    if ([temp length] == 0) {
        temp = @"0";
    }
    [Screen setText:temp];
}
```

It works, but whenever I enter another number, it resets back to the whole thing, so lets take this as an example.

I have the number 5678, (I deleted 678), So my new number is 5, (Now if I press another number), it goes back to 56781 ( 1 being the new number)

Heres my full code for my project! --->   http://txt.do/oduh

Comment: I don't think your saved the current number.You just show the current number.

Comment: How would I exactly save the curet number? Because I see what you mean by that! Sorry, but I'm a bit new to programming D:

Comment: Save it into variables by `SelectNumber = temp;` as Yogesh mentioned.When you use `SelectNumber ` ,you can get the newest number.

Comment: I did that, but like i stated to him, I get a bunch of random numbers!  I'd followed a tutorial! and if I enter in the numbers 865, then delete 5, then If I were to enter 6 right after that, I get the numbers = 1691696.. A bunch of random numbers!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in your code, you are using `SelectNumber` to store value everywhere, but in `deleteButton` method you are not storing new value in `SelectNumber`. So you need to set the new value in `deleteButton`.

```
- (IBAction)deleteButton:(id)sender {
    NSString *string = [Screen text];
    int length = [string length];
    NSString *temp = [string substringToIndex:length-1];

    if ([temp length] == 0) {
        temp = @"0";
    }
    SelectNumber = [temp intValue]; // set new value here
    [Screen setText:temp];
}
```

Comment: Woah wait, now when I do it, if I were to press 643 and delete 3 then press another number, a load of numbers just appear on the screen! For the code you just put in, what do you mean by set new value here? Do I put something their? I'm a bit new to programming!

Comment: @SirRyan If you are new to programming, how did you have written that much of code? Also what do you mean by `a load of numbers just appear on the screen`?

Comment: I'd followed a tutorial! and if I enter in the numbers 865, then delete 5, then If I were to enter 6 right after that, I get the numbers = 1691696.. A bunch of random numbers!

Comment: Ohh my god! Yes, Thank you so much Yogesh you're the best! Honestly I've been trying to figure this whole for 6 hours today, no joke! :D

Comment: I have one more question, on my very first comment link, I left a website to my code! So for my Screen (Result) label how would I make it so if my answer was a whole number to show 2, instead of 2.00. and if it was 2.45 show 2.45, do you kind of understand what I mean by this?

Comment: Wait I will, but I just have one more question for you before I accept the answer!